# MySQL setting a constant array to a variable

Tags: mysql, arrays

I am tryong to set a constant list of the uids of the dev team of a project so I can later in my MySQL script exclude them from queries with something like `.. where user not in @dev_team_ids ..` but I am getting this error:

```
mysql> set @dev_team_ids = (1,2,4);
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: can you post your query and constant values code ? so I can look into ?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have arrays in the usual sense. You can use a temporary lookup table containing your values, or you can use a string with comma-delimited values, in conjunction with `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
set @dev_team_ids = '1,2,4';

.. where not FIND_IN_SET(user, @dev_team_ids) ..
```